# Dockerfile execute additional scripts in entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I'm building a `lamp` container for development work from [glats/alpine-lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/glats/alpine-lamp). I want to run some additional sql commands (create a DB and some test users) after the container loads. I've created a new `init.sh` script that I'm running as my Dockerfile's entrypoint, like this:

```
FROM glats/alpine-lamp
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
COPY init.sh /init.sh
RUN chmod u+x /init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/init.sh"]
```

In my `init.sh` I'm executing the parent container's [entrypoint script](https://github.com/glats/alpine-lamp/blob/master/entry.sh), but since this script doesn't exit and doesn't run in the background, my additions never get executed. I've tried a few different ways of calling the parent script, including `source entry.sh`, `/bin/sh /entry.sh`, and `(/entry.sh)`. I also tried sending it to the background using `/entry.sh &`, though this didn't work either.

What's the right way to add additional entrypoint scripts to a container when the parent script doesn't exit?

EDIT: my init script

```
#!/bin/sh
#run the parent container's entry script
/entry.sh &

# now run the rest of the stuff that needs to happen
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think based on the fact that there are other ways to run initial queries after the mysql is running, you should try to approach this from another angle.
For example you can use volumes to set the `./conf/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
something like what [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/796762/creating-a-docker-mysql-container-with-a-prepared-database-scheme) is showing

EDIT:
you can also put .sh files in the directory, it's not only .sql files.
They are executed in alphabetical order.
There is a better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482630/2596409) and [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for the thought @vahid. I think that will work for the SQL part, but I still need to run some cleanup stuff (not SQL) after the parent container's init finishes.

Comment: @user101289 I edited the answer, You can also put .sh files there.